# How to generate and show increasing number on a webpage without relading the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, api, web-development-server

The number will start increasing after deploying the webpage. Let's assume the number will grow from 1 to 10000 and increment by 2/any calculated number in every 1 min. Every time you visit the page, you will see the current number. For example, if you visit the page 500 min after deploying the site, it will show let's say 832. Revisit after 2 min, it will show 836(incremented by the number we set). And you can see it increasing without reloading. Here server will generate the number and keep sending updates. The client will see it live.

Comment: Use `setInterval` to update the page while it sits there. As for calculating the proper amount of minutes, just hardcode the deployment date into the page, and calculate the amount of minutes that have passed using `Date`.

Comment: This will show us not the right time if the users send the computer in sleep-modus and than continue because while the pause it will be not updated.

Comment: @Sascha if we follow Chris G's example then this will not be a problem.

Comment: I agree with you but sometimes this is a problem e.g. if you want to automatically logged of from a page after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Write the deployment time in a hidden field in your HTML. At start and then in intervalls of 60 seconds call a update-function where you calc the time between deploy and now. The result can be formatted because it is in ms and updated in your HTML.

I extra don't increase at every call with 1 minute because the user could send the computer in sleep-modus and than continue. Then the minutes will be although paused because while the pause it will be not updated.

**Remark:** This solution assumes that on server and clientside is used the same timezone otherwise you have to look for a solution with UTC-time.

```js
let deploy= document.getElementById('deploy').innerHTML;
let date = new Date(deploy);

updateDeploy();
setInterval(updateDeploy, 60000);

function updateDeploy() {
    let elapsed = parseInt((new Date() - date)/60000);
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = elapsed;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='deploy' class='hidden'>2020-08-05T09:24:00</div>
Time elapsed<div id='minutes'></div>
```

Comment: In case my question is confusing as I gave the example of incrementing 1 in 1 min. Here, I am not trying to calculate date/time has passed since the deployment. I am trying to send any calculated number that updates in every 1 min. For example- It will keep showing the next fibonacci and update in every 1 min and keep increasing. The change will happen in server side but it will keep updaing to the client live. For example it will show 5, in next minute 8, then 13 and it will keep updating. I dont have any problem with the sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

For real-time updates on a client-faced site, where the "soure of thruth" is the server, I would definitely recommend websockets. `socket.io` is a wonderful library for that. That way you won't have to reload the site or request anything over and over again.

Something like :

```js
// server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

setInterval(() => {
  // sending the current time-since-deploy to all clients
  io.sockets.emit('update-time', timeSinceDeploy);
}, 1000);
```

```js
//client
socket.on('update-time', (elapsed) => {
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = elapsed;
});
```

How to setup socket.io specifically you directly get from their documentation ( https://socket.io/ )

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read the documentation. However, some people are confusing "my problem" with "calculating the time/date" as I gave the example of incrementing 1 in 1 min. Here, I am trying to send any calculated number that updates in every 1 min. For example- It will keep showing the next fibonacci number in every 1 min and keep increasing.  You are right- The change will happen in server side but it will keep updaing to the client live.

Comment: Then this should give you an idea on how to do this. I didn't focused on calculating a number, I focused on "sending the number to the frontend" . You let server calculate the current number and keep it but send updates to clients with the current number per interval. All the client does is receiving updates from the server.